# Mathjax library (MathView) is not rendering certain latex code (like matrix, unit vectors etc) in android,

Tags: android, latex, mathjax

[here is the image link with three questions with 1st and 3rd being matrix and equation respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EjdC.png) Here is my latex code for a matrix :

```
\(\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{3--x}&2&2\\2&{4--x}&1\\{--2}&{--4}&{--1--x}\end{array}} \right|\)
```

And latex code for equation with unit vector:

```
\(\mathop E\limits^ \to = ({E_0}\mathop i\limits^ \wedge + 2{E_0}\mathop j\limits^ \wedge )\)
```

They work perfectly fine with angular 5 but not in android (MathView)

Comment: Please describe what actually does not work on android?

Comment: @AntonBelousov I have added the image you can see that the above code is not rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, all I had to do was `mathView.setEngine(1)`. The default value for engine is `0` which is for `KATEX` and `1` is for `MATHJAX`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message in the posted image comes from chunk.

Check if all `{% exec %}` blocks have their corresponding end marker `{% endexec %}`

Comment: Alright I will check, but what about the question no 3. with unit vectors?